# Set theory formula

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I picked up a copy of Jech's *Set Theory* at my school library and I'm reading through it and taking notes. Right at the beginning, though, he mentions something called a 'formula'. Here's the quote:

"Concerning formulas with free variables, we adopt the notational convention that all free variables of a formula $\varphi(u_1, ..., u_n)$ are among $(u_1, ..., u_n)$ [...]"

What does this mean? What is $\varphi(u_1, ..., u_n)$?

Comment: Do you know what a formula is?

Comment: I assume it is a series of logical  connectives?

Comment: Maybe Jech isn't for *right now*. Maybe Enderton's books would be more fitting?

Comment: You can see [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/) a brief overview of logic with the (in)formal specification for a *first-order* formula.    An example in the language of set theory is : $\forall x \ (x \in y \to x \in z)$; in it, we have three (individual) *variables* : $x$ (bound) and $y,z$ (free). Thus, the formula is "like" $\varphi(x,y,z)$, becuase all free variables in it are among $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If you post that as an answer- I will give you accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA69) (2nd ed - 2001), Section 2.1. : **First-Order Languages**, page 69-on (and you can see also this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802963/in-mathematical-logic-what-is-a-language) for a relevant quotation from Enderton's book).

Consider an example in the language of *set theory* :

> $∀x \ (x∈y \to x∈z)$.

In it, we have three (individual) variables : $x$ (bound) and $y,z$ (free); thus, the formula is "like" $\varphi(x,y,z)$, because all free variables in it are among $(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 5):

While Jech's Set Theory is my favorite textbook, it isn't suitable as a starting point into mathematical logic. Thus, even though I strongly encourage anyone interested in set theory to read his book, you should study (at least) some basics of mathematical logic first.
Over at mathoverflow, there is a post [asking for textbooks on mathematical logic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61814/ask-for-recommendations-for-textbook-on-mathematical-logic) that provides some suggestions where to start.

I haven't read it, but [this course on mathematical logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) by Stephen Simpson is available for free and seems to cover the basics (judging from its index alone) up to a point, where Jech might be remotely readable afterwards... (At this point, it will still be a huge stretch... Jech's target audience is graduate students and researchers in set theory).

---

To adress miracle173's comment:

You are looking for the definition of a formula in first-order logic. To rigorously define these and their meaning, one has to introduce languages, quantifiers, connective symbols, free/bounded variables, structures, assignments and the modeling relation. Any introductory textbook on mathematical logic will define these objects. Therefore, I consider the above a reasonable answer to your question.

Comment: Tjis may be a useful advice for the OP but it is not an answer to the question.