# Which are concepts undefined? which are symbols in the language of set theory?

Tags: first-order-logic

> I know that in the most general terms, when we talk about a mathematical 
>   theory, we have in mind a collection of **axioms** and **Undefined Concepts** in a **certain language**.

Now in **axiomatic set theory** ;

- Which are concepts undefined?
- which are symbols in the language of set theory?

Comment: What do you mean by  `Undefined Concepts`? and in the language of $\sf ZFC$ the only symbol is $\in$

Comment: In set theory "set" and $\in$ are undefined.

Comment: There is no single answer to this.  In any axiomatic theory, we may take concepts A and B to be "undefined" and define concept C in terms of those, or take B and C to be "undefined" and define A in terms of B and C.

Comment: @drhab there are set theories with Urelements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Urelements_in_set_theory

Comment: @Holo .for example in esuclidean geometry :undefined Concepts are point ,...

Comment: @Almot1960 why not? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry)#Points_in_Euclidean_geometry

Comment: @drhab . why is not '='?

Comment: See the post [In Mathematical Logic, What is a Language?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802963/in-mathematical-logic-what-is-a-language).

Comment: Oh, undefined as in "open to interpretation"(not logical symbol, part of the language)? If so only $\in$, all other objects are definable using $\in$, even $=$(in $\sf ZFC$)

Comment: @Holo .how defined '=' by $\in$ ?

Comment: @Almot1960 x=y: $\forall z(z\in x\iff z\in y)\land \forall w(x\in w\iff y\in w)$

Comment: @Holo .let $x,y$ be a element . then $x \in y$ or $y\in x$ It is meaningless .because we say that $x$ is an element of $A$ (is a set no element) .

Comment: @Almot1960 I am not sure what you mean. I defined x=y using only ∈ and logical symbols, if x,y∈A it does not mean x∈y or y∈x

Comment: @Holo .let $A=\lbrace 1 ,2,3 \rbrace$ and $B =\lbrace  1 \rbrace $ now we want to say : "$1=1$" . How is that ? . $1 \in 1$ It is meaningless .

Comment: @Almot1960 in $\sf ZF$ all objects are sets, 1 is usually defined as $\{\emptyset\}$, that is why I said $\sf ZFC$ at the end there

Comment: @Holo .ohhh . thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory ($\mathsf {ZF}$)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html#AxiSetThe) :

> is an axiom system formulated in [first-order logic with equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax) and with only one binary relation symbol $\in$ for membership.

Thus, its language is that of first-order logic, with sentential connective symbols: $→,¬, \lor,\land$; *individual variables*: $v_1, v_2, \ldots$; the *equality symbol* $=$; and the *quantifier symbols*: $\forall, \exists$.

In addition to them, the theory has only one (binary) predicate : $\in$ to mean "membership". It is the only "undefined" concept of the theory.

With them we can formulate the [axioms of $\mathsf {ZF}$ set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html).

One of the axioms is the **Null Set** axiom :

> $∃x \ \forall y \ \lnot (y ∈ x)$.

Using this axiom and the **Extensionality Axiom** it is provable that the set satisfying the axiom is unique.

Thus, we may introduce the *defined term* "$\emptyset$" (a new symbol) to denote it.

---

*Note*

The most common formulation of [$\mathsf {ZF}$ set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) is based on FOL with *equality*.

Thus "$=$" is part of the background logic, that means that the usual axioms like $∀x(x=x)$ are assumed.

There are versions where the background logic does not include equality "$=$"; in that case $x=y$ may be defined as an abbreviation for :

> $∀z[z∈x ↔ z∈y] ∧ ∀w[x∈w ↔ y∈w]$,

with a suitable reformulation of the **Extensionalty Axiom**. In that case, the usual properties of = must be proved from the above definition.

Comment: Should "=" be ?

Comment: @Almot1960 Should "$=$" be *what*?

Comment: In language of the set  should be equality symbol ? or defined equality symbol  by $∈$ ?