# Why the language of set theory involves only $\in$?

Tags: first-order-logic

I’m reading **A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic** and in Example 1.2.3, they write:

> The language of set theory is not very complicated at all. We will include one binary relation symbol, $\in$, and that is all:$$ L_{ST} ~is~ \{\in\}$$

But I think, when we use set theory we usually write things like:
$$
x \in X \\
1,2,3 \cdots n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

That is, the language involves the letters and numbers also. So, why the book has not included that in its $L_{ST}$?

Comment: Because set theory is about (mathematical) objects **belonging to** ($\in$) sets.

Comment: The theory is general, and thus the only "basic" ingredients are the $\in$ relation and the empty set. Other mathematical objects are build-up from them (according to the axioms of the theory).

Comment: In set theory, everything is a set (unless we allow urelements). So, $0 \in 1 \in 2 \in 3 \in ...$ is technically true (using the von Neumann definition of natural numbers where $n+1=n \cup \{n\}$).

Comment: In set theory, numbers are not "basic" sets but they are defined (mathematical) objects.

Comment: Variables, connectives and quantifiers are not "objects" the theory deals with, but part of the language used to speak of.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But the language involves "objects", so why not to include it in?

Comment: "involve" is not (maybe) the correct word. Language **speak of** objects and is **made of** symbols.

Comment: Maybe useful [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042559/which-are-concepts-undefined-which-are-symbols-in-the-language-of-set-theory) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802963/in-mathematical-logic-what-is-a-language)

Comment: See also the post[What exactly is a formula in set theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028366/what-exactly-is-a-formula-in-set-theory)

Comment: For a different approach, more similar (I think) to your intuition, see [CTT](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic/#PropType)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is this formulation of Goldbach Conjecture in a language $\mathcal{L} ~is~ \{0, S, +, \cdot, <\}$ :
$$
(\forall v) (S(S(0)) \lt v)( \exists u)(v = S(S(0)) \cdot u) \implies (\exists p) (\exists q) ( v = p+q \land Prime(p) \land Prime(q) )
$$
Where $S$ is the successor function and Prime (x) is symbol to denote that $x$ is a prime number. 

Is my formulation correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many set theories, but the most common one, is ZFC. I will
talk only about ZFC, because I do not know every set theory that exists
and I do not want to make generalizations that do not hold. ZFC is
a theory in first order logic. That means that it has not only the
symbol "$\in$", but also all symbols that the language of first
order predicate calculus has, like the symbols of variables, the parenthesis
"$($" and "$)$", the logical connectives "$\neg$", "$\land$", "$\vee$", "$\rightarrow$", "$\leftrightarrow$", or some of them, the quantifiers "$\forall$" and "$\exists$", or at least one of them and perhaps, the equality symbol "$=$".
All the symbols that belong to the language of logic, are called "logical"
symbols.

Of course, one cannot express everything using logical symbols alone.
In order to apply logic in other fields of mathematics, one must expand
its language with all the symbols that are necessary for that field.
Those are called "non logical" symbols and they are listed in
the "signature" of the language. Because the logical symbols are
taken for granted, it is convenient to describe a language only by
its non logical symbols. When somebody says "*the language of set
theory has only the symbol "$\in$"* ", he means that it has
only "$\in$" in its signature. That is: beyond the logical symbols,
the only symbol is "$\in$".

Now, why does ZFC only needs "$\in$" as non logical symbol? Because
it is enough to formulate all the axioms of that theory, and because
everything else results from the axioms. So, every statement of set
theory can be expressed by the logical symbols and "$\in$", alone.
Then, what about symbols like "$\varnothing$", "$\cup$",
"$\subseteq$" etc? Well, those symbols are used for convenience,
but they are not necessary. Everything that can be written with them,
it can also be written without them. For example, "$a\subseteq b$"
is equivalent to: "$\forall x\left(x\in a\rightarrow x\in b\right)$".
The first is just an abbreviation of the second. Or, lets take $a\cup b\neq\varnothing$.
This is equivalent to $\exists c\left[\forall x\left(x\in a\vee x\in b\leftrightarrow x\in c\right)\wedge\exists y\left(y\in c\right)\right]$.
It is not forbidden to include non necessary symbols to a signature - in fact, we often do - but it is not necessary either. If we do not include such symbols, the formal language does not have them, and every formula that is made of them, does not belong - strictly speaking - to the formal language. In practice, we often use them, but it is easy to translate our formulas in the strictly formal form, whenever is needed.

In your question, you also mention natural numbers. There are is a
definition of natural numbers, from the polymath John von Neumann,
based on ZFC. He defines 0 as the empty set, and the successor of
a number $n$ is $n\cup\{n\}$. This gives: $0=\varnothing$, $1=\{0\}=\{\varnothing\}$,
$2=\{0,1\}=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, $3=\{0,1,2\}=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$...
Then, the set $\mathbb{N}$ of all natural numbers, is the smallest
set that contains $\varnothing$, which is closed under the function
$s(n)=n\cup\{n\}$. In this way, every proposition that contains numerals,
can be translated to a proposition that contains only logical symbols
and "$\in$".

However, if you do not use von Neuman definition, and your numerals
have a different meaning, which is not definable inside ZFC, then
you may have to include some of them in the signature, together with
other necessary symbols, from which you will define the rest. In that
case, you have created an extension of your language, which is not
the language of set theory any more.

Comment: I have never heard about ZFC, or maybe I have just forgotten it. But a google search tells me it is an abbreviation for Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory for anyone else who might be wondering.

Comment: It may be a silly question to ask but can you please tell me if $x$ and $X$ are variables in $$x \in X$$? (variables in the sense of first order logic language symbols).

Comment: If they have a certain value, then they are constants. If they can take different values, then they are variables.