# How to introduce non-logical axioms?

Tags: logic, axioms

Suppose I have a deductive system based on the language $L=\{Variables,\vee,\wedge,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow,\neg\}$ consisting of propositional tautologies and rules of inference. How do I introduce non-logical axioms? More precisely, do non-logical axioms have to be formulas of $L$ exclusively, i.e. non-tautologous formulas expressed only with the logical symbols $\vee,\wedge,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow,\neg$ of $L$, or can they be expressed in a stronger language involving additional symbols, like $\forall,\exists$, e.g. ZFC (I guess, in that case, they have to be stated separately)?

Comment: What do you mean by non-logical axioms? Something like the Peano Axioms?  If so, yes, you need some language that specifies certain predicates, functions, and/or constants. E.g if you want to have $1+1=2$ you’ll need sone way to represent $1$, $2$, and $+$… only the $=$ is part of pure logic.

Comment: See [First-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Peano_arithmetic_as_first-order_theory) for non-logical axioms. Example: $\forall x\ (0\neq S(x))$

Comment: "expressed only with the logical symbols ∨,∧,→,¬ of L, or can they be expressed in a stronger language comprising additional symbols, like ∀,∃, " Quantifiers are "logical symbols".

Comment: A mathematical theory add some non-logical symbols, like the binary predicate $\in$ for set theory and the function symbol $s$ for arithmetic and states non-logical axioms regarding them.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802963/in-mathematical-logic-what-is-a-language) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042559/which-are-concepts-undefined-which-are-symbols-in-the-language-of-set-theory).