# What is the formal definition of a function symbol in first order logic?

Tags: functions, definition, first-order-logic

Is the function symbol in first-order logic is the same as a function? If not, what is the definition of a function symbol?

Comment: No, it's just a given 'character' of first order formulas which syntactically are just strings of characters. All we have besides the symbol, is the *arity* of it, i.e. how many arguments it takes (in the syntax).

Comment: See the post [In Mathematical Logic, What is a Language?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802963/in-mathematical-logic-what-is-a-language) for example.